# Why is my "Quantity" undefined?

Tags: mysql, node.js

```
function checkForItemId() {
  console.log(userItemID);
  console.log(Quantity);
  connection.query("SELECT * FROM products WHERE id = ?", [userItemID],
    function(err, results, fields) {
      if (err) throw err;

      product = results[0];
      Name = product.product_name;
      Department = product.department_name;
      Price = product.price;
      Quantity = product.stock_quantity;

      if (Quantity >= userItemQuantity) {
        console.log("We have enough");
      } else {
        console.log("We do not have enough of that");
      }

    });
}
```

Why is my "Quantity" variable console logging as "undefined"? I am not totally familiar with transferring data from a table in my sql to javascript, but I think this is how I would do about it based on other examples. What am I doing wrong that giving that error?[image]

[image]

Comment: Can you please share the function call and check if you have to pass any arguments to the function?

Also, can you check for the variable name and its scope of declaration?

Answer (score -1):

It's undefined, because you define it later in your function. Try to `console.log` it after you get results from your query.

Comment: I did. It still said undefined?

Comment: Another reason might be that you are getting an error in your query function

Comment: @VamsiKrishna Make sure you do it in the callback function, since it runs asynchronously.

Comment: Ok. Would you know how to fix that?

Comment: @Barmar What do you mean? And do either of you know how to get the query function working?

Comment: Put it right before `if (Quantity >= userItemQuantity)`

Comment: It looks like `if (err) throw err;` is executing. Try using `console.log(err)` there to see what the error is.